# How to remove Width and Height values of an Image with css?

Tags: html, css

It has been supposed that all of child images of a `div` (with `id="leaderboardimage"`) have a width value of 100%. So we have:

```
#leaderboardimage img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-width:100%;
max-width:100%;
}
```

But now I want to add a new image to this div but I do not want to apply the above styles. How can I reset the width and hight values of this particular image( it is nested in an element with `class="creatortag").

the below styling does not work:

```
#leaderboardimage .creatortag img{
width:auto;
height:auto;
min-width:0;
max-width:100%;
}
```

Here is sample of HTML:

```
<div id="leaderboardimage">
    <a class="creatortag">
         <img  /> an exception for the genarl css rule
    </a>
    <img />ordinary images
    <img />ordinary images
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Change your original CSS selector to `#leaderboardimage > img {}`

Comment: @TylerH this is not a solution to OPs problem.. in fact it's completly unrelated as both images are within `#leaderboardimage`

Comment: @TylerH Thank you very good idea. But for my general knowledge I also want to know how to reset the values.

Comment: @Daniel Well, it was a comment, not an answer. Further, it actually *is* a solution and is completely relevant. It will cause the original CSS to only apply to the two img elements outside of the nested `a` tag, which has an img in it that he wants to style differently. Did you read the question?

Comment: @TylerH I see - and got your point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector for your CSS, instead:

`#leaderboardimage > img {}`

The styles will be applied only to the `<img>` elements directly under the `<div id="leaderboardimage">` (not to elements that are nested within other elements inside the div).

Personally, I would define a style for a class within CSS and assign that class to the images I want to style.

Comment: Thank you and thanks to TylerH. It solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

To reset a max-value you use the `none` keyword. To reset a min value you use `0`. So...

```
#leaderboardimage .creatortag img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
```

...should do it.

(Note: resetting a max value to 100%, by the way, does not 'default' the max-width, as 100% could still be smaller/bigger than the actual image width because of a wrappers width)

Comment: It did not reset the values in a way that it never had been set previousely

Comment: This is the way to reset max and min values, however, so it must be conflicting with other set values. (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
#leaderboardimage img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
a.creatortag {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#leaderboardimage .creatortag img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="leaderboardimage"> <a class="creatortag">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> an exception for the genarl css rule
    </a>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />ordinary images
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />ordinary images</div>
```

You can cancel out the original styles of `min-width:100%;` and `max-width:100%;` by adding `min-width: 0;`and `max-width: none;` to the styles of `#leaderboardimage .creatortag img`.

Answer (score 0):

If possible then apply inline style. They are at the top priorities.

```
<div id="leaderboardimage">
    <a class="creatortag">
         <img  style="height:auto;width:auto;" /> an exception for the genarl css rule
    </a>
    <img />ordinary images
    <img />ordinary images
</div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't actually reset the max- or min- values, though. It is also not recommended, as style changes now require HTML and CSS to change.